# IndexError: list assignment index out of range when deleting passed in index

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

I am trying to delete an item from a list given a certain index by passing in both the list and index. I am getting an index error though when I am attmepting it. Im not sure how it can be out of the range of the index. I am using python 3.

```
def removeTasks(k, toDo):
    del toDo[k]
    return toDo
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs of the function which can regenerate the error?

Comment: This is on the CodeFIghts website. I know this wouldnt be an issue with a number in the index. The test puts in index value 10 with a length of 1 in the index. I am not allowed to alter any code other than whats there with the toDo[k[

Comment: Okay, may be they want you to handle the situation with a simple `try/except` block.

Comment: def removeTasks(k, toDo):
    del ...
    return toDo
Im not sure as the code only allows for the ellipses to be changed

Comment: Actually, this is very difficult to give a solution without knowing the full problem. Please add the minimal example that can reproduce your problem. Though this is not encouraged, you can perhaps add the link of the problem, if you are unable to describe the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is some invalid keys, you can use `try/except` block to handle that. You can rewrite your function like below:

```
def removeTasks(k, toDo):
    try:   
        del toDo[k]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    finally: 
        return toDo
```